# При первой загрузке не отображаются HTML тег созданный в JS

Tags: javascript

Создал страничку `HTML` c категориями товаров.
Создал два простых `JS` файла.
В первом в виде константы прописал объект который содержит массивы.
Причем каждое название массива это другие странички `HTML` (их 9 штук)
сам массив содержит всего две позиции `['Y','что выводить, если Y']`
Примерно так:

```
const actionPage = {
    accessories: ['Y','что выводить, если Y'],
    index:['Y','что выводить, если Y'],
    vs_slippers:['Y','что выводить, если Y'],
```

и т.д.
загрузку этого скрипта разместил сразу под открытием `body`
Затем перед закрытием `body`
Вписываю:

```
 <script>
    window.onload;
</script>
<script src="js/start-ind.js"></script>
```

В втором скрипте `start-ind.js` одной из функций я проверяю текущий адрес странички window.location.href, а затем проверяю есть ли массив с таким именем в объекте actionPage, если есть и у него на 0 позиции "Y" то формирую два тега.
Первый тег формирую после открытия body вешаю на него `addEventListener`, что б по клику открывалось модальное окно. Второй тег это и есть то самое модальное окно.
Проблема в следующем:
При локально запуске, все отрабатывает как надо!
Но как только я запускаю с реального хостинга ни один из тегов не формируется!!!
Причем, если перейти по любой ссылке на этой странице, которая есть в объекте `actionPage`, то на новой странице появляються оба тега, а если снова вернуться на предыдущую страницу по ссылке на новой странице, то эти оба тега то же появляются и при обновлении страницы не исчезают! Как с этим бороться!
на всякий случай сайт:

если на https://My-domen/vs-robe.html (или сразу открыть), а потом по внутренней ссылке вернутся на домашнюю страницу index.html, то видно как появляються и не исчезают при обновлении страницы эти теги. Но стоит открыть в соседней вкладке https://My-domen тегов опять нет !

Уже разобрался! ниже написал почему так происходит!

Comment: Локализуйте проблему, возможно тогда и сами найдёте ответ. Сократите рассказ и код до того момента, где что-то не работает. Уберите всякие массивы, меню, несколько скриптов и прочее лишнее.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, чем полнее описание, тем легче понять проблему (дьявол кроется в деталях). Если б ответ мог найти - не писал бы сюда. Аналогичные странички отличающиеся от индексной только фото и текстовым контентом формируют эти узлы, а посадочная , только при переходе на неё с любой другой!

Comment: Разобрался! Проблема была в следующем:
Когда я проверял локальный адрес - в нем всегда присутствовал index.html, а на хостинге он без него https://My-domen. В моем переборе при сверке брались данные после  последнего слеша, но без раcширения .html
Но после перехода на эту страницу с любой другой в адресной строке появляется https://My-domen/index.html

Comment: Полное описание не даёт лучшего понимания. Вы просто ставите другого человека на своё место. Гораздо легче понимать проблему, когда из неё выброшено всё лишнее. У вас в рассказе много чего написано, но не всё из описанного играло роль. Например важен ли был рассказ о подключении разных скриптов, о массивах и меню? Нет. И я об этом писал выше.